# Form not posting data into mysql Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to post some data from my HTML form into my mysql database.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#BCB7B7">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" style="text-align:center" action="post.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  <p></p>
  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Age">
  <p></p>
  <input type="text" name="food" id="food" placeholder="Food">
  <p></p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","mydbname");
mysql_select_db("mydbname",$connect);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES Name = $_POST[name],  Age = $_POST[age], Food = $_POST[food]");
?>
```

but the data does not get saved

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `("localhost","myusername","mypassword")` you chose the DB name below. Plus, your values are way off AND open to SQL injection. It's not `Name = ...` it's just the value itself. Do read proper tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in SQL must be quoted. You are dumping your variables into the SQL without quotes.

Your syntax is also wrong. The format is `INSERT INTO table_name (column_name, column_name) VALUES value, value`.

You are also failing to escape the data, so you are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

To fix your problems:

1. Stop using the deprecated `mysql_` library and switch to `mysqli_` or `PDI`
2. Use bound arguments to insert variables into your SQL
3. Use the correct syntax

This [question about preventing SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has examples of [how to use those libraries safely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different versions of the `INSERT` command - you are using neither.

Either:

```
INSERT INTO myTable SET Name = "Peter", 
Age = 15, Food = "pizza"
```

or

```
INSERT INTO myTable (Name, Age, Food) VALUES 
("Peter", 15, "pizza")
```

Comment: *"Either: `INSERT INTO myTable SET Name`"* - That is incorrect. That would need to be `UPDATE myTable SET Name = "Peter"...`

Comment: @Fred-ii- - you are mistaken.  It's a less common syntax, but some people like it.  If you don't believe me, go read the mysql manual.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: My bad, sorry about that Sam. I stand corrected. Will +1 for my mistake ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the values:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES Name = '$_POST[name]',  Age = '$_POST[age]', Food = '$_POST[food]'");
```

Hint: You should use mysqli_ or PDO_ functions as mysql_ functions are deprecated

Comment: **Danger**: This is still vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I know that. He should read some tutorials about proper and safe inserting form data into sql db. I only fixed his issue

Comment: *"Hint: You should use mysqli_ or PDO_ functions as mysql_ functions are deprecated"* --- The use of `mysqli_` and/or PDO are **not** safeguards against SQL injection; not on their own that is. Using [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or **PDO** with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) will.

Comment: I did not say those are safeguards. I only said that mysql_ functions are deprecated. I see you quoted my answer ... where did I say that using those provide safeguard? :)

Comment: I was merely "stating" that the use of those are not safeguards, and wasn't putting words in your mouth. People get the wrong impression and think that by using `mysqli_` and/or PDO, that SQL injection won't happen. I honestly don't know where people get that misconception about thoses APIs.

Comment: neither do I. you provided some links there. They should read them :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","mydbname") or die("error while connecting to the database");
mysql_select_db("mydbname",$connect) or die("error while selecting the database");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[name]) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[age]) . "', '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[food]) . "')");
?>
```